# error installing app engine sdk

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, sdk

When I try to install AppEngine SDK in eclipse, I get this error, downloading and installation of the package runs for some time and then I get this error.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://dl.google.com/eclipse/appengine/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.5.jar.
Read timed out
```

I tried on windows and ubuntu, faced the same problem twice.
What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to follow [this link by Google](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse) while installing the appengine sdk in your eclipse. If you need only appengine sdk check it and also check the Google Plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: I was able to install it on the second attempt when it resumed from previous. But I wonder why the error occurred twice. That is why posted this question.

Comment: There may be problems sometimes. Sometimes with Eclipse. Sometimes from the resource from where it is fetching the files for sdk or plugin to be integrated with eclipse.